# Sound effect to end a music track on a TV promo?

Tags: sound-design, television, commercials

What is the best way to end a music track on a TV promo when the music doesn’t have a definite end?

I sometimes hear an effect but I’m not sure how it’s done. I don’t think it’s a backwards reverb, delay or sound element added outside of the track. It’s more like a reverb but has a definite end.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to post links to some examples? Also, what is the style of the music you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

End it with someone talking

example: *commercial starts* -> *music plays* -> *commercial ends* -> "Jai jian real estate, because home is where the heart is"

:P

Answer (score 1):

Hire a composer to write music that fits.
The extra polish that results can count for a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'll sometimes do a an edit to get a large drum hit or nice part of the music at the end but also use a transition effect or some cymbals and then a pretty dense reverb and fade it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use the end of the chorus or the end of some section of the song that signifies a change is coming as to not end it abruptly. On top of this, I would quickly fade out the and throw on some reverb as well as to not have the ending too abrupt. However, all songs are different so this may not work for your track. Out of interest, what is the track?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all of the options above, if you can jimmy it so that you end at a decent place in the phrasing, you can add a low plunk on piano or bass on the tonic note of the song, maybe with a cymbal hit, to signify a resolution to the music

Answer (score 0):

You need to build it up a little towards the end and then do a sudden halt with big koto or tom like drum hit whit some verb tail/whatever else as long it's single and distinguished sound and leave some rolling off sounds of buildup.

In dubstep terms: do an uplifter with some additional wobbly build up, finish it with huge reverberated kick and some quickly fading, but slowing tail from the wobble. Hope you can translate it to your needs.